# remove the last character of the line if it is a

Tags: text-processing

I have a file of the form

```
bulandshahara   b u l a n d sh a h a r a
caandapura  c aa n d a p u r a
```

I have to remove the "occurrence of a space followed by a" if this pattern appears at the last of any line.

My expected output would be

```
bulandshahara   b u l a n d sh a h a r
caandapura  c aa n d a p u r
```

How can I do this?

I visited [Remove characters if they do not follow specified patterns](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/253836/remove-characters-if-they-do-not-follow-specified-patterns) but it was about deleting characters if they did not follow the pattern.

My question is to remove characters "at the end of the line" if they follow the pattern that I have specified.

Comment: is this homework?

Comment: no, actually I was working with a project and got stuck with this. my original file contains about 15000 lines. So, i am trying to do with a script.

Answer (score 4):

`<"$YOUR_FILE" sed 's/ a$//' > $NEW_FILE` will do the trick i think.