# How can I find the first missing directory in a long path?

Tags: bash, shell, directory, ls

Imagine I have a path that doesn't exist:

```
$ ls /foo/bar/baz/hello/world
ls: cannot access /foo/bar/baz/hello/world: No such file or directory
```

But let's say `/foo/bar` *does* exist. Is there a quick way for me to determine that `baz` is the breaking point in the path?

I'm using Bash.

Comment: `access(2)` is not very granular, so the solution typically involves writing something to iterate and test each path element in turn...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given a canonical pathname, such as yours, this will work:

```
set -f --; IFS=/
for p in $pathname
do    [ -e "$*/$p" ] || break
      set -- "$@" "$p"
done; printf %s\\n "$*"
```

That prints through the last fully existing/accessible component of `$pathname`, and puts each of those separately into the arg array. The first nonexistent component is not printed, but it is saved in `$p`.

You might approach it oppositely:

```
until cd -- "$path" && cd -
do    case   $path  in
      (*[!/]/*)
              path="${path%/*}"
;;    (*)   ! break
      esac
done  2>/dev/null   && cd -
```

That will either return appropriately or will pare down `$path` as needed. It declines to attempt a change to `/`, but if successful will print both your current working directory and the directory to which it changes to stdout. Your current `$PWD` will be put in `$OLDPWD` as well.

Comment: Clearly: `for p in $pathname` will be subject to "word splitting" and "Pathname expansion".

Comment: @BinaryZebra - yes, it is split on `$IFS`. that's exactly how it works. it is not subject to pathname expansion, except that the variable here called `$pathname` is expanded to an array of path components as split on `$IFS`.

Comment: You are avoiding the "Pathname expansion" on var `$pathname`  by using `set -f`" which is not returned to its default value.

Comment: @BinaryZebra - im not avoiding anything. im specifying the environment i need in order to do this robustly. thats all. no - its not returned to its *default value* and neither will it install itself on the asker's computer or make me breakfast.

Comment: And in the process of setting your environment, change the environment for any code following.

Comment: @BinaryZebra - there is no code following. if someone wanted to append some they might or might not want to reset `$IFS` and globbing before they do. Or they might just run it in a subshell - or as its own script. Should someone want to reset those to defaults they could do it like `set +f; IFS='`*`<space><tab><newline>`*`'`. Have you any other pressing concerns of which I should be made aware?

Comment: @BinaryZebra - by the by, if, as any good programmer should, you often find yourself worrying about unnecessarily affecting/recovering your execution environment, you might take an interest in [`ns`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/254401/52934), which, if used here, would render this discussion moot.

Comment: For posterity: I had to add `pathname="$1"` to get this code to run on my command line argument. Just going with `for p in $1` didn't work.

Comment: This approach will fail if one of the existing folders in our path was "chmod 000 dir" (i.e. no one can read/write/execute). But if you use "sudo namei" then it will correctly indicate that folder and will continue digging. The error of this approach is an assumption that we can "cd" into components.

Comment: @DmitryShevkoplyas please dont encourage the use of `sudo` anything when dealing with path components. of course if your file system is configured to keep your username out of a path, this will not allow you in. you can `sudo cd` all day, too.

Answer (score 15):

One of my favourite utilties is [`namei`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/namei.1.html), part of [`util-linux`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Util-linux) and hence generally present only on Linux:

```
$ namei /usr/share/foo/bar
f: /usr/share/foo/bar
 d /
 d usr
 d share
   foo - No such file or directory
```

But its output is not very parseable. So, if you just wish to point out something is missing, `namei` might be useful.

It's useful for troubleshooting general problems in accessing a path, since you can get it to state whether a component is a link or a mount point, as well as its permissions:

```
$ ln -sf /usr/foo/bar /tmp/
$ namei -lx /tmp/bar
f: /tmp/bar
Drwxr-xr-x root    root    /
Drwxrwxrwt root    root    tmp
lrwxrwxrwx muru    muru    bar -> /usr/foo/bar
Drwxr-xr-x root    root      /
drwxr-xr-x root    root      usr
                             foo - No such file or directory
```

The capital `D` indicates a mount point.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I hoped equivalents might be present on other systems. Nothing for the BSDs?

Comment: `namei` works for me as long as a feed it a path that exists, but when I give it one that doesn't I get `namei: failed to stat: /usr/share/foo/bar: No such file or directory`.

Comment: @kuzzooroo which version of namei?

Comment: my version of namei does not give a version in its help nor its man page and does not support a flag giving version info. I am able to determine that it comes from the package linux-utils 2.16-1ubuntu5 but can't figure out what that implies for the version of namei.

Comment: @kuzzooroo Since even [Ubuntu 12.04 has 2.20.1](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=util-linux), you must be on a very old version of Ubuntu indeed. 10.04?

Comment: Yes, ancient indeed: when I'm on Linux, it's 9.10 (this is in an enterprise context in which we're very careful about when we upgrade). Most of the time I'm on a Mac, but as far as I can tell there's no namei port.

Comment: I've accepted one of the answers below since they aren't linux-specific, but this is what I would use if I were working on a modern version of Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this (accounting for pathnames with embedded blanks):

```
#!/bin/sh
explain() {
    if [ -d "$1" ]
    then
        printf "\t%s: is a directory\n" "$1"
    elif [ -e "$1" ]
    then
        printf "\t%s: is not a directory\n" "$1"
    else
        printf "\t%s: does not exist\n" "$1"
    fi
}

for item in "$@"
do
    last=
    test="$item"
    printf "testing: '%s'\n" "$item"
    while [ ! -d "$test" ]
    do
        last="$test"
        test=$(dirname "$test")
        [ -z "$test" ] && break
    done
    if [ -n "$last" ]
    then
        explain "$test"
        explain "$last"
    else
        printf "\t%s: ok\n" "$item"
    fi
done
```

Comment: It assumes the arguments are meant to be directories (or symlinks to directories).

Comment: if you just `cd not_a_directory` your shell will just write to stderr something like *`cd:cd:6: no such file or directory: not_a_directory`*. Actually, the user's shell will do so in a format with which the user is probably already very familiar. Its almost *always* both easier and better in the end anyway to just *do* stuff and let the shell handle the reporting as necessary. That kind of philosophy though does require a very strict attention to return values and the promotion/preservation of same.

Answer (score 1):

Just an alternative solution for bash, assuming the path is an absolute path (starts with /)  :

```
#!/bin/bash

pathname="$1"

IFS='/' read -r -a p <<<"${pathname#/}"

pa=""    max="${#p[@]}"    i=0
while (( i<"$max" )); do
      pa="$pa/${p[i++]}"
      if     [[ ! -e $pa ]]; then
             printf 'failed at: \t"%s"\t"%s"\n' "${pa##*/}" "${pa}"
             break
      fi
done
```

---

```
$ ./script "/foo/ba r/baz/hello/world"
failed at:      "hello"        "/foo/ba r/baz/hello"
```

Comment: This worked for me. I needed the last valid path in the path string, so I saved `pa` as `pa_prev` as the first line of the while loop (before it gets incremented). When the test for "pa" then fails, `pa_prev` has the last existing directory in the given path.

Comment: This approach will fail if one of the existing folders in our path was "chmod 000 dir". But if you use "sudo namei" then it will correctly indicate that folder and will continue digging deeper. The error of this approach is an assumption that "test -e" will be able to look inside "not allowed to look" folders. This can be fixed if instead of "[[ ! -e $pa ]]" one would first: "sudo test -e ${pa}" and then check "if [ $? -ne 0 ];", then it will look deeper. To be fair: if you run "namei" w/o "sudo", then it will give you "permissin denied" on "chmod 000 dir", which is more clear/expected output.

Answer (score 0):

```
(( dirct=$(echo ${dir}|tr "/" " "|wc -w)+1 ))
i=2
while [ ${i} -le ${dirct} ]
do
  sdir=$(echo ${dir}|cut -d/ -f1,${i})
  if [ ! -d ${sdir} ]
  then
    echo "Path is broken at ${sdir}"
  fi
  (( i++ ))
done
```

it is not simple but you can put it in a script, make it executable and stick it somewhere in your path, if you are going to use it frequently.

Caveat emptor: If your directory name at any level contains a `space` character, this will NOT work.

Comment: Is this bash code? I had to swap in ${dir} was coming up blank so I swapped in $1, but now sdir is coming up blank for me.